# knockout- Google maps marker filter

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating a google map that by default shows a few markers. When the user enters a particular location, the marker for only that location has to remain and the remaining works have to disappear. While the markers and the maps are working, the filter functionality is not working.My JS code is as follows:

```
function inintMap()
{

var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId : 'roadmap'
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

var locations = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];



for (i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
{ var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations [i][1],locations [i][2] );
bounds.extend (position);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : position,
    map : map,
    title : locations [i][0]
});


        map.fitBounds(bounds);


}



var vm =  {
     locations: ko.observableArray(locations)
 };


 vm.query = ko.observable('')
 vm.search = function(value){

    vm.locations.removeAll()

    for(var x in locations) {
      if(locations[x].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        viewModel.locations.push(locations[x]);
      }
    }
  }


vm.query.subscribe(vm.search);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

`vm.locations.removeAll()`. From that code you have already removed all the locations before you can even search from it. Search through it first and put the searched locations in another array, then you can just replace the locations with the new array.

```
vm.search = function(value){
    var tempLocations = []; 
    for(var x in vm.locations()) {
      if(vm.locations()[x].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        tempLocations.push(vm.locations()[x]);
      }
    }
    vm.locations(tempLocations);
}
```

Also, take note that when referring to observablearrays, you need to call it as a function, don't forget your parenthesis.